# jQuery append img src URL

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I need to submit img url. Once submitted, it should be appended as an image in the list below the form. How can add image URL value to the list? Currently I have this code but it does't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

      let postPic = $('#imgLink').val()
      $('#imageList').append($('<li>' + '<img src=$("postPic")>' + '</li>'))

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example code this should work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#imageList').append($('<li>' + '<img src="' + $('#imgLink').val() + '">' + '</li>'))
  });
});
```

Comment: why should be the code like that what is wrong with OP's code? answer without explanation is not helpful to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have already gotten the value of your img src into the postPic var, this is a string so doesn't need to be inside the jQuery selector. This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let postPic = $('#imgLink').val()
    $('#imageList').append($('<li>' + '<img src="' + postPic + '">' + '</li>'))

  });
});
```

Effectively, your mistake was trying to select an html element with a selector matching the value of postPic instead of assigning the value of postPic to the src of the img element.

Answer (score 0):

I'ved tried this code and it works. You only have to call `postPic` so that the value of the inputted url in the `imageListForm` form will display to the `img` source.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      let postPic = $('#imgLink').val();
      $('#imageList').append($('<li>' + '<img src="'+postPic+'"' + '</li>'));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

  let postPic = $('#imgLink').val()
  $('#imageList').append("<li><img src='"+postPic+"'></li>");

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imageListForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

      let postPic = $('#imgLink').val()
      $('<li>' + '<img src=$("postPic")>' + '</li>')
      $('#imageList').append($("<img/>"),{
          src: function() {
            return postPic
          },
          class: function() {
            return imageClasses
          }
      })

    });
  });
```